# Is there a Rails library that can track unique errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, sentry

Is there anything for Rails that is similar to [Sentry for Django](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry)?

The main functionality I'm after is automatic deduping exceptions so emails aren't repeated for the same error.

Here is a screenshot of Sentry to explain the functionality visually:

[image: Sentry screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A workmate directed me to a Ruby client of Sentry. Even though the server is a Django server, we can still use Rails to report to it.

It's called Raven-Ruby: https://github.com/getsentry/raven-ruby

Answer (score 4):

Errbit can do it and is free (also self hosted) -- https://github.com/errbit/errbit

There are several commercial offerings including Airbrake, exception.io, and I'm sure some others...

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Airbrake.io ?